Deleting noncontiguous lines in vim with a single command
Is there a way to delete multiple noncontiguous lines in vim using a single command?
Here is an example:
     3  numeral_dict = {
     4      'M': 1000,
     5      'CM': 900,
     6      'D': 500,
     7      'CD': 400,
     8      'C': 100,
     9      'XC': 90,
    10      'L': 50,
    11      'XL': 40,
    12      'X': 10,
    13      'IX': 9,
    14      'V': 5,
    15      'IV': 4,
    16      'I': 1,
    17  }

I want to delete lines 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, and 15 (so that I can move them to a separate dict).
Is there a way to do this in a single command?
I tried searching and no tutorials seem to show this. I'm not sure if this is a limit to vim. Everything only shows the ability to do this using a contiguous range of line numbers.


Everything only shows the ability to do this using a contiguous range of line numbers.

You can only use a continuous range.
Depending on how thin you are willing to stretch the meaning of "single command", this might qualify as one:
:15d|13d|11d|9d|7d|5d

Note that this must go upward because going downward would change subsequent line numbers.
Did you look around for a plugin?

You're missing the "so that I can move them to a separate dict" part of the question. Assuming the new dict starts at line 20, you could tweak your command to :15m20|13m20|....

Thanks both romainl and Friedrich. This ended up being the solution. I know I'm stretching "one command" but it certainly does what I needed.
I had tweak the commands following to take into account the lines that had been moved right before for this final result for the answer:
5m18|6m18|7m18|8m18|9m18|10m18

I would avoid using line numbers, but instead I would try to focus on what exactly I want to get rid of.
In your example, let's say it's CM, CD, XC, XL,  IX and IV. In that case I'd write
:g/\vCM|CD|XC|XL|IX|IV/d_


:h :g
:h :d
:h quote_
:h /\v
:h /\bar

Note: I may use line numbers when I'm obtaining them programmatically. In that case, I would have a list of numbers obtained with map()+filter() and then I'd use these numbers in a loop.
PS: :g can also be used to trim every other line in a selected range -- as you seem to be doing in your example. See How to delete every other line in Vim?

Thanks for the post.
I wanted to delete these with a single delete so that I could extract the lines and paste them somewhere else. However, it seems vim does not support deleting noncontiguous lines with a single delete.
This was the workaround I used based on another user's recommendation:
:5m18|6m18|7m18|8m18|9m18|10m18

Instead of deleting, g would have supported incremental copy by yanking in a capital letter register. 1. :let @a = '' 2. g/\vCM|CD|XC|XL|IX|IV/y A 3. go where ever you want and finally: 4. "ap

This is not one single command, but it scales up with any number of lines. First you record the first line and then repeat it 5 more times to delete all 6 lines you want to delete:
:5  " go to line 5 (if you are not already there)
qq  " start recording in register 'q'
dd  " remove current line (line 5)
j   " move down one line (down to former line 7, now line 6)
q   " stop recording
5@q " repeat register 'q' 5 times

You can then also repeat the pattern stored in 'q' anywhere else you need it.
